# How to exit fullscreen mode from flash on a touchscreen

Tags: flash, methods, fullscreen, exit, touchscreen

i need to know all methods to exit from a fullscreen mode of a flash application on a touchscreen (because i want that people exit with my custom button).

I know that with a traditional desktop, ESC of the keyboard and double click with left button of the mouse allow to exit from fullscreen (like youtube).

Anyone know the methods for touchscreen? (no keyboard, no mouse)

Thank you,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

The only "built-in" way of exiting fullscreen mode on Android is with the device's "Back" button. It works with hardware buttons for Android 2.x and for the software back button on Android 3.x tablets.

Incidentally, on desktops only the Escape key exits fullscreen. In youtube, the SWF is detecting double-click and changing modes, Flash isn't doing that automatically.